# Accessing a global variable inside nested functions

Tags: php, function, variables

Here's my scenario:

```
$foo = bar;

one()
{
   two()
   {
      three()
      {
         // need access to $foo here
      }
   }
}
```

I know I could pass $foo down all three functions, but that isn't really ideal, because you may or may not require it, besides, there are other parameters already and I don't want to add to that list if I can prevent it. It's only when you get to `three()` do you need `$foo`. I know I could also specify `global $foo;` in `three()`, but I read that this wasn't a good practice.

Is there another way `$foo` can be made available to `three()` without doing either of those?

To provide a little more info, $foo in this case is info on how to connect to the database e.g. server, user, pass, but only in `three()` does it actually need that info. Of course I could connect to the database right as the document loads, but that feels unecessary if the document might not need it.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**: I'm sorry, I didn't mean to have "function" at the beginning of each function implying that I was created them in a nested way.

Comment: Are you really using nested functions for real?

Comment: As a general rule, don't ever nest function definitions... it's a pointless exercise in both code and coder confuscation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `global` is not a bad practice if used properly. This case you would use `global` and it will be totally fine.

Since `global` makes functions get access to global variables, there are data corruption risks. 
Just make sure to use with caution and you know what you're doing (i.e. not accidentally change the data that you don't want it to change. This sometimes causes some nasty bugs that's hard to track.)

Summarize: `global` in this case is perfectly fine.

What's really bad is nested functions, at least in PHP.

Comment: "What's really bad is nested functions, at least in PHP." -- why so?

Comment: Using `global` IS bad practice absolutely ALWAYS.

Comment: @OZ_ With great power comes great responsibilities. As long as you practise safe `global` usage, you'll be fine.

Comment: @Ryan, it's bad because it makes the code difficult to read. Also the inside function only exist inside the wrapper function. Rule of Thumb: Simplicity is better than complexity.

Comment: there is no any 'safe' using for `global`. It's self-delusion.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can use `global`, or pass it through as a parameter. Both are fair ways. However, I'd do the latter. Or, you can also use [closures](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) and the `use` keyword:

```
$foo = 'bar';

$one = function() use($foo) {
   $two = function() use($foo) {
      $three = function () use($foo) {
         // access to $foo here
      };
   };
};
```

Can also be `use(&$foo)` if you need to modify the top `$foo`'s value inside of `$three()`

Answer (score 0):

Don't listen anybody, who are speaking about `global`.
Read books about OOP (e.g. [this one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590599098)), read about Dependency Injection, Factory-patterns.
Dependency Injection is the best way to create flexible and easy-to-maintain code, and by DI philosophy you will pass $foo from first to third function in arguments, or will pass Context object with all necessary variables (if you want to minimize count of arguments).
More about DI you can read here: http://components.symfony-project.org/dependency-injection/trunk/book/00-Introduction

Comment: You're not really explaining why `global` is bad practice in this situation. PHP is technically OOP, but is rarely used in any sort of complex OOP structure.

Comment: @melkamo `global` is evil in any situation. This code can not be reused, can not be moved in code, can not be tested and very hard in refactoring.

Comment: Well, that depends entirely on the purpose of the function. Not all functions are standalone entities that you'd want to move around. Nor should they all have to be.

Comment: @OZ_: Once again, you fail to explain. Tell me this: if I have a series of private functions inside a class, and the class is a well-defined entity that will not be broken down into parts, that what could I possibly lose from using global variables within its private functions? Nothing.

Comment: @melkamo `you fail to explain` lol, I just won't spend my time to explain obvious things. If you use `global` in your code - your code smells. So man, don't play in `once again`, go read some books.

Comment: In other words you can't answer the question. I've read plenty of OOP books thanks since my background is Java - but PHP sure isn't Java.

Comment: @melkamo without any other words. Your code is bad, don't use `global`. I even did explain 'why', but if you don't want to listen - it's your problem.

Comment: @melkamo if you trying to say that 'Java is cool, you all just noobs in your PHP', then read this: https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.xml#Static_and_Global_Variables

Comment: @melkamo and read this, it's exactly about Java: http://misko.hevery.com/code-reviewers-guide/

Comment: Style guides are exactly that: guides. In the example I gave, `global` will not result in harder maintenance, and will save you passing a variable through to lots of functions lots of times. In other situations, it shouldn't be used, sure. But it's up to the programmer to decide. And no, I'm not promoting Java as "cool" - I rarely use it these days. I mainly use Python, which is practically the anti-Java. I'm simply saying that not all OOP principles are relevant to PHP. Thanks for the Java link though, I hadn't seen that.

Comment: @melkamo global variable between two methods creates 'lying' signature of methods. `private function priv_func() { global $a; }` - in declaration of method we don't see, that $a is necessary, and we can create error here. And more: if some another method will use global $a for his own needs, there can be LOT of bugs. And it's only tiny explanation - using `global` is VERY bad practice, lot of bugs and limitations can be achieved with `global`s.